# An uncommitted transaction updates a column; how can a different transaction see the old column value?

Tags: sql-server, update, transaction

Let's assume the following case.

There is a `students` table:

```
id | name
-----------------
1  | Mateus
```

A "User A" executes the following statement without committing the transaction:

```
update students set name = 'Gustavo' where id = 1
```

Then a "User B" executes the following query:

```
select * from students with (nolock) where id = 1
```

User B will get the name `Gustavo`, that's the expected behavior. The DB will return the uncommitted value because of the `with(nolock)` instruction.

Is there a way to get the old name, `Mateus` (the previously committed value), even when there's an uncommitted transaction?

Comment: Do you mean to have a `with (nolock)` in your `select`?  It sounds from the text hat you do but the actual query does not...

Comment: It sounds like you may be thinking of [Optimistic Isolation Levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server) such as `SNAPSHOT` or `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` isolation levels where a read is not blocked by a prior uncompleted transaction.

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer and also more presentable (although I'll agree the latter is often subjective). Please feel free to edit further as you see fit.

Comment: You may try readpast as lock hint to get last committed record however RCSI is the best possible option.

Comment: So basically the only option available is changing the DB settings globally, no way to do it via query level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Read Committed Snapshot Isolation (RCSI) on your database, which uses space in TempDB to keep track of committed versions of the data.

Be aware that RCSI adds 14 bytes to every versioned row, so you might see some additional page splits in the database. It also requires that TempDB's space and I/O be monitored to make sure it's not slowing things down.

Read more by [Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation) and in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5014/what-risks-are-there-if-we-enable-read-committed-snapshot-in-sql-server).